# Changing two or three bars an octave lower on Guitar

Tags: guitar

Is it allowed to change two or three bar notes an octave lower in a song *(one tab or sheet music)* for Guitar?

for this reason some Guitar have 12 frets like mine
and this is link *[(midnight express)](http://www.azchords.com/m/miscsoundtrack-tabs-5376/midnightexpresstheme-tabs-75373.html)* has bars 13-14 15.

Answer (score 1):

Allowed by whom? If someone asks you to play exactly *that* tablature, you should play it as it is. If you have any restrictions, it is not illegal to change an octave lower for some notes. So, change it.

It will sound different, and it might not sound exactly like you wanted it, but it is acceptable. Try and see if you can lower the whole song or some mote parts an octave lower .

It is common for guitarists to change the melodies up and down octaves; this might prevent them from getting bored by playing the same thing over and over again.

Comment: And is it proper to change lower from G to F or E?

Comment: There is a difference in changing octaves and changing notes. If you want to lower a G to F or E, you will have to lower all the notes a tone or a tone and a half respectively. This is acceptable, yes

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to play frets past the 12th fret on your instrument, then you will not be able to play the linked tablature as it is written.

You can certainly play the same notes one octave lower.  But **if you shift certain measures by an octave, and you don't shift all of the other notes in the tabbed arrangement by the exact same amount (one octave) then your melody will no longer be the same.**

An integral and defining feature of any musical work is the direction that the melody moves as it progresses.  In some parts the notes go in an ascending direction (go higher) and in other parts they go in a descending direction (go lower) - often spanning one or more octaves over a given number of measures.  Using the same notes but changing only some notes by an octave without changing the other notes, can potentially change the effect of the entire song and it will no longer be recognizable as the same tune.

Tablature does not attempt to identify notes as much as it attempts to tell you what string and fret combination to play in whichever tuning the author dictates.  Two tabs written exactly the same could indicate completely different notes if one was intended to be used with an alternate tuning of the guitar.

The challenge in lowering a particular arrangement written in tab by one octave, is that you must first identify each note in the original tab.  Then you will have to find where on the guitar you can play that same note one octave lower.  In most cases it will be on a different string.  It's not really an easy thing to do unless you are very familiar with the names of all the notes on the fretboard and all the alternate places each note can be played one octave lower.

If you can't find an alternate tab for the same song that is already written one octave lower, you can create your own tab.  Go to this link **[Blank Tab Template](http://www.justinguitar.com/images/RS_images/BlankTab.pdf)** and download the template and print as many sheets as you need.  Convert the tab you want to your new version by taking each note and finding the same note one octave lower on your guitar and writing it on your blank tab template.  You can do this by ear and trial and error if you don't already know where to find the octave lower note on your fretboard.

Later when your budget allows, if you want to play arrangements that call for notes to be played on the 15th or 16th fret, you might want to get a guitar with more frets and perhaps a cutaway to allow easier access to those higher notes.

Have fun.